# Автоматическая регистрация с обходом капчи

Tags: php, javascript, captcha, recaptcha

Стоит задача автоматически заполнять поля формы, подтвердить капчу и отправить данные. Нужно автоматизировать эту задачу за исключением подтверждения капчи. NoCaptche от Google пользователь будет подтверждать на нашем сайте. Вопрос:
как в теории можно это сделать?

Comment: откуда данные то должны браться? откуда пониматься? если человек первый раз зашел на страницу, система о нем знать не знает. Совсем не понятна задача. Если пользователь заходил уже на страницу, и вводил что-то, это одно, а если впервые....

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, Грубо говоря нужен своеобразный сервис, который располагается на нашем сервере. Сервис должен заполнять поля формы заранее известными данными. Оператор этого сервиса должен только вводить капчу(При необходимости)

Comment: пользователя можно идентифицировать если он когда либо входил, т.к. можно в `localStorage` сохранить некую информацию о ней, но тут уже проблема безопасности, придется генерировать ключ для пользователя, чтобы его нельзя было подменить. Я не вижу проблемы в реализации этого

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, вы не совсем правильно поняли вопрос. Нужно сделать так, чтобы на СТОРОННЕМ сайте(yandex.ru) например автоматически регистрировались аккаунты. Вся проблема в капче. Нужно чтоб наш специально обученый человек просто подтверждал их(На нашем сервере)